# How can I determine why my whirlpool refrigerator has stopped running water?

Tags: repair, refrigerator

We have a Whirlpool refrigerator that's 2 years old which suddenly stopped running water. What can I do?

Comment: Have you contacted Whirlpool?

Comment: Have you checked the filter?  If the refrigerator has been re-positioned recently, maybe the hose is kinked or the water valve was shut off?

Answer (score 1):

Water inlet valve is probably fubar.  Part is probably here (YMMV):  http://bit.ly/1wkXC4G

How to video here:  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eNGe_VUDIBA

Good luck!